# Ignore parameter if null SQL error in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2013

Hi I am attempting to pull a query from an access database using an SQL string and I am having difficulty getting the code to work correctly. If I use the following code

```
" select [incident id] as incidentid, ([incident ID] &' '&[incident date]) as incisearch from incident where (@supplier is null or [stock supplier] = @supplier)"
```

It will only return a result if a parameter for @supplier is entered, if I use the following code

```
" select [incident id] as incidentid, ([incident ID] &' '&[incident date]) as incisearch from incident where ([stock supplier] is null or @supplier)"
```

It will only return the results for null regardless of what parameter is entered @supplier. I have tried several combinations/variations of this code this morning and I cant get it to work to display all results if @supplier is null and to display relevant results when @supplier parameter is entered. Can someone please tell me where my code is wrong?

Comment: where ([stock supplier] is null or [stock supplier] = @supplier)

Comment: The first one should work. Are you sure @supplier is null? are you sending DBNull as a parameter?

Comment: I am not sending DBnull as a parameter, I dont know how that works. The paramter setting I am using is Dim supplier As New OleDbParameter("@supplier", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                    supplier.Value = txt_supplier.Text
                    command.Parameters.Add(supplier)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> where ([stock supplier] is null or @supplier)
> ```

It is always worth testing your SQL, with sample data, directly first.

You would have found this is a syntax error, there is no `column = a or b`  like expression syntax. Instead you need something like:

```
where (([stock supplier] is null) or ([stock supplier] = @supplier))
```

or, more likely:

```
where ((@supplier is null) or ([stock supplier] = @supplier))
```

which will always be true (returning all rows) if the parameter is itself null.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have tried both of these and it is still only showing results when I enter a value in @supplier

Comment: Try the SQL directly against the database (manually substituting in parameters as Access does not support SQL variables). Any errors should give you clues as to the problem.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late response, So I have tried the SQL direct in access which works when giving a supplier parameter, so that part works fine, I dont know how I can test the is null part as I assume for this I would just leave out the where part of the SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below snippet

```
select 
   [incident id] as incidentid, 
   ([incident ID] &' '&[incident date]) as incisearch 
from incident 
where ([stock supplier]=isnull(@supplier,[stock supplier]))
```

Comment: Depends is [stock supplier] can be null or not.